# Limitation of an Azure Data Factory Web Activity to read JSON file from Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having a JSON file in the Azure Blob Storage. My aim is to read the contents of the JSON file using a Web Activity and pass the response to the body of the next Web Activity.

At the moment, the JSON file in the Blob storage is having couple of rows, and the pipeline is running successfully, achieving the goal.

My question is: Is there a limitation to the Web Activity to read only n number of rows from a file?
Like, I mean, we know that the limitation of a Lookup Activity is that, it can only read 5000 rows. Is there any similar sort of limitation while reading using a Web Activity?

What if, JSON file in the Blob storage is having 500000 or even more number of rows? Will the Web Activity be able to read all the rows from the JSON file?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity?) for Web Activity and notice the note at the top:

> Note
>
> The maximum supported output response payload size is 4 MB.

I would recommend you [vote for this feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/bb60ae2d-6e26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) or [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/4fa9dce8-6d26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).